What security advantage does executing privileges have?
Say some sysadmin has no problem with their users reading the files in /sbin, but doesn't want them running them. Take for example /sbin/initOne rebellious user used ld.so /sbin/poweroff instead. Figuring this out, the sysadmin blocks executing access to ld.sowhich is no problem because the user can simply copy over /bin/ld.so to their home directory and use chmod +x ./myld.so
./myld.so /sbin/init The sysadmin can't deny read access to /bin/ld.so because it is a symbolic link to /lib/ld-linux-architecture.so, and doing so would render the system basically useless for the rebellious user.
What is the point of the executing privilege then?

The execute permission bit on files isn’t really a security feature, it’s mostly about distinguishing files which are executable from files that aren’t.
Execution security is handled by other system features. For example, administrators who don’t want to allow users to run arbitrary binaries can ensure that any directory users can write to is on a noexec mount point. Privilege escalation, such as setuid binaries, relies on properties that are lost when binaries are copied: the setuid bit, entries in configuration files such as sudoers or pkexec profiles, etc.


Say some sysadmin has no problem with their users reading the files in /sbin, but doesn't want them running them. Take for example

Then that admin is lost. Any user can
cat /sbin/program > ~/program # only needs read privileges
chmod o+x ~/program
~/program

So, that makes no sense. Two exceptions:

the original might have the suid bit set.
the original might have security xattrs that restrict it further (SELinux, Apparmor, other LSMs…)

The second thing isn't going to be relevant. That's an additional restriction vs executing a copy of the executable as a user.
The first thing: yep, that's a problem. But the solution is almost without exception to move away from setuid binaries, towards mechanisms where a process doesn't gain privilege that the starting user doesn't have. (You can consider complex sudo rules being preferred a questionable stopgap measure, that's at least advantageous in that you can at least fine-tune who can execute what as different user through /etc/sudoers. It's too error-prone, imho.)
Such mechanisms are pretty widespread on non-GNU/BSD userland "human interfacing" OSes (namely, Android, Windows, MacOS, iOS, MBOS, to name the few that come to my mind): You never launch a "system-modifying" command as unprivileged user yourself that suddenly gets root access, because that's just an invitation to find bugs that allow you to make that program do whatever you want it to do (a curated list of *nix programs you can make execute whatever you want them to execute).
For example, a popular thing is that on scientific compute servers, backup clients are given suid – so that a normal user can run a backup of their whole environment, to a storage service that they cannot access regularly. Great idea, aside from being able to specify the compressor on the command line, which then runs as root. Use a script that spawns a telnet server and otherwise passes through the input to the output uncompressed; done, there's your backdoor.
Instead, there's a system management deamon, spawned by the init process (~equivalent), which the unprivileged user sends very well-defined requests to, which internally checks the privileged (typically, using a centralized mechanism for that), and then does the pre-configured operation.
This is perfectly well illustrated by your /sbin/poweroff example. For Linux distros these days, shutting down is a complicated process – you need to check whether the requesting user has the right to do that, you need to check nobody else is logged in, you need to unmount all the things that the logged in user might have mounted themselves, including network file systems, stop their user daemons (from their emacs -d to their steam client!), save their work, close their application programs, log them out, initiate the shutdown sequence, take down things in the right order (musn't shut down network while the system NFS mount is still syncing data!)…
I haven't seen a multi-user Linux system where /sbin/poweroff is just a suid shutdown script in maybe a decade. I'm sure BSDs have the same problem and handle it similarly. So, if that problem exists, then because the administrator left his system in the mid-1990s. Time to do something about that!
Linux desktop userland has long shifted towards this. Your Linux desktop doesn't call a Suid mount anymore to mount the USB stick you just plugged in and want to open as unprivileged user, it requests access from a disk management daemon. Works beautifully (and, having been there, soooo much more reliable, nicer and less error-prone that Linux of the late 90's/early 2000's).
So, coming back to your question:

What is the point of the executing privilege then?

It allows you to restrict which files are immediately executable. As said, that makes a difference in the presence of SUID and other file-bound security mechanisms; it makes a difference to whether you can use something as interpreter for a file format, and it tells your shell that when you type "nano", that you want /usr/bin/nano to be executed, and not the text file called "nano" that just happens to have ended up somewhere else in your path.


What is the point of the executing privilege then?

Mostly that it prevents inadvertent execution of files that actually contain no executable code or scripts. Files like README.txt.
Your observation that denying the execute permission of a program file while allowing users to read it is futile is absolutely correct: anything the user can read, they can copy; and the new copy will be theirs to set permissions as they see fit.
But in some situations, you might wish to grant the execute privilege without the corresponding read privilege. One example might be programs that have setuid/setgid privileges assigned to them. Some proprietary Unix systems (and some hardening guides) might set the permissions of e.g. /bin/passwd to ---s--x--x, owner root, to discourage users from attempting to find weaknesses in the setuid binary by using a disassembler or other debugging tools on it.
In open-source operating systems like Linux and BSD, such micromanagement of permissions can be considered unnecessary since the source code of those setuid/setgid programs is freely available to anyone anyway.
Even so, the kernel and drivers still dictate which operations require more privileges than regular users have. Having access to an executable copy of /sbin/ifconfig as a regular user might allow you to view the network settings of the system, but if you try to change them, all you're going to achieve will be a "Permission denied" error message.
And if you try and copy a setuid or setgid binary, you'll find that many filesystem drivers will automatically strip those permission bits off when writing to a file, so those bits will need to be explicitly put back after writing is done... but without root (or equivalent) privileges, you absolutely cannot produce a new file that would be owned by anyone other than your own user account, so even if you could preserve or re-add the setuid bit, the copy would not be setuid root, but setuid yourself. It would not give you any privileges you didn't already have, and having it around might allow other users to impersonate you.
The same is true of the setgid bit: if you try to add a setgid bit to a file owned by a group your user account is not already a member of, the request to add a setgid bit will be silently ignored.
See man 2 chmod:

If the calling process is not privileged (Linux: does not have the CAP_FSETID capability), and the group of the file does not match the  effective  group ID of the process or one of its supplementary group IDs, the S_ISGID bit will be turned off, but this will not cause an error to be returned.

